# Database encoding cakephp search

Tags: database, cakephp, encoding

I have a database with names and I need to look up a name and get results from both with as without special chars.

Problem is that the names in the database are not saved correctly.

Example: 
I need to look up the name 'Mariën'. I have a 'Marien' and a 'MariÃ«n' in my database; But it gives no results...

**In my core:** 
    `Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');`

**Database**

> utf8_general_ci for the database
>
> > utf8_general_ci for the table
> >
> > > varchar(100) utf8_general_ci  for the field

Anyhelp on this part?

Comment: What encoding are the names in your database saved as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your database configuration in `Config/database.php` set with `encoding` => `utf8`?

If not cake isn't talking with the DB in UTF8 but rather in Latin1 or something.